# android menuItem.setIcon not working every time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I have menuItem in fragment A, the menuItem.setIcon work fine the first time, but when I Add fragment B (not replace) and go back to fragment A, the menuItem.setIcon is not working anymore!

here is my code on fragment A, the buttonClicked method work perfectly before I add the fragment B and go back to fragment A

```
private MenuItem menuItem;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_item);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


public void buttonClicked() {
    if (condition)
        menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action));
    else
        menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_checked));
}
```

Comment: i think you are setting your icons in onCreateView() which is not getting called when you go back.if you want to set your icons again and again either you set icons in onResume() method or replace your fragment instead of adding it in fragment transaction.For more information check the life cycle of fragment.

Comment: Are you setting the menuItem.setIcon in onCreateOptionsMenu method??

Comment: @sunilkushwah  I set the icon when I click a button, and I need to add the second fragment not replace the first one

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: @sunilkushwah please check my updated question

Comment: is there any crash after clicking the button

Comment: no crash, and when I debug the buttonClicked method executed but no change in the menu item icon

Answer (score 2):

you need to call Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(); to make any menu changes.